# How to pass tests correctly in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

**The problem:**

I'm trying to write a TypeScript function suitable for a previously written JEST test. There are 5 tests in total. The function I wrote passes all the tests, but unfortunately, I was asked to write again in the review. How to write this more efficiently?

**Example case:**
Imagine an array that contains folders. These folders can have files in it. move function moves a file to another folder and returns the new state of given list.

Example list:

```ts
const list = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
  },
]
```

If I run move(list, '4', '6') then I expect file with id 4 moved to the folder which has id 6. Function should return the new state below;

```ts
const result = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [
      { id: '7', name: 'File 5' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
    ],
  },
]
```

move.ts

```ts
type File = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

type Folder = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  files: File[];
};

type List = Folder[];

export default function move(list: List, source: string, destination: string): List {
  let sourceFileIndex = -1;
  let sourceFolderIndex = -1;
  let destinationFolderIndex = -1;

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    const { id, files } = list[i];

    if (id === source) {
      throw new Error('You cannot move a folder');
    }

    if (id === destination) {
      destinationFolderIndex = i;
    }

    if (destinationFolderIndex > -1 && sourceFileIndex > -1) break;

    for (let j = 0; j < files.length; j += 1) {
      if (files[j].id === destination) {
        throw new Error('You cannot specify a file as the destination');
      }

      if (files[j].id === source) {
        sourceFileIndex = j;
        sourceFolderIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (destinationFolderIndex === -1) {
    throw new Error('Given destination id did not match any folder');
  }

  if (sourceFolderIndex === -1) {
    throw new Error('Given source id of file was not found in any folder');
  }

  list[destinationFolderIndex].files.push(
    ...list[sourceFolderIndex].files.splice(sourceFileIndex, 1),
  );

  return list;
}
```

move.spec.ts

```ts
import move from './move';

describe('move', () => {
  it('moves given file to another folder', () => {
    const list = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Folder 1',
        files: [
          { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
          { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
          { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
          { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        name: 'Folder 2',
        files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
      },
    ];

    const result = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Folder 1',
        files: [
          { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
          { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
          { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        name: 'Folder 2',
        files: [
          { id: '7', name: 'File 5' },
          { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
        ],
      },
    ];

    expect(move(list, '4', '6')).toStrictEqual(result);
  });

  it('throws error if given source is not a file', () => {
    const list = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Folder 1',
        files: [{ id: '2', name: 'File 1' }],
      },
      { id: '3', name: 'Folder 2', files: [] },
    ];

    expect(() => move(list, '3', '1')).toThrow('You cannot move a folder');
  });

  it('throws error if given destination is not a folder', () => {
    const list = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Folder 1',
        files: [{ id: '2', name: 'File 1' }],
      },
      { id: '3', name: 'Folder 2', files: [{ id: '4', name: 'File 2' }] },
    ];

    expect(() => move(list, '2', '4')).toThrow('You cannot specify a file as the destination');
  });

  it('throws error if given source was not found', () => {
    const list = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Folder 1',
        files: [
          { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
          { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
          { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
          { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        name: 'Folder 2',
        files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
      },
    ];

    expect(() => move(list, '9', '6')).toThrow(
      'Given source id of file was not found in any folder',
    );
  });

  it('throws error if given destination was not found', () => {
    const list = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Folder 1',
        files: [
          { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
          { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
          { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
          { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        name: 'Folder 2',
        files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
      },
    ];

    expect(() => move(list, '4', '9')).toThrow('Given destination id did not match any folder');
  });
});
```

As I said, it passed 5 tests but was not accepted. What is the problem?

Comment: This question is better suited for the CodeReview stackoverflow.

Comment: most probably they want the whole thing be immutable and didn't like destructive operations `push` and `splice` in your code.